# ruby &:method syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I ran into a bug where i left out a space like this

```
@entries = [#<Entry id: 3806, approved: false, submitted: false]

@entries.any?&:submitted? => true
@entries.any? &:submitted? => false
```

how does the space change the behavior. Entry.submitted? => false for all the elements in the array, the second line has the desired behavior.

Comment: Works for me, 1.8 and 1.9, with a trivial `class Entry; def submitted?; true end end`.  Can we see the smallest possible code you have that reproduces the issue?

Comment: 1.8.7 REE works great with spave and without space `[1,2,nil].any?&:nil?` and `[1,2,nil].any? &:nil?`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that & is also a Unary Operator that has a precedence.

When you do this:

```
@entries.any?&:submitted?
```

You are actually doing is this:

```
(@entries.any?)&(:submitted?)
```

Which results in true. Since there are entries in @entries and the symbol :submitted? has a truth value of true.

When you do this:

```
@entries.any? &:submitted?
```

What you are actually doing is this:

```
@entries.any?(&:submitted?)
```

Which is what you really want.

The reason @pilcrow got his to work is that he/she was using the following class:

```
class Entry
  def submitted?
    true
  end
end
```

To reproduce the result, use the following class:

```
class Entry
  def submitted?
    false
  end
end
```

P.S: Same thing with @fl00r's example:

```
[1,2,nil].any?&:nil? and [1,2,nil].any? &:nil?
```

[1,2,nil].any? results in true and :nil? has a truth value of true, so the results are the same since [1,2,nil] also contains a nil value, but the calculations are different.

Comment: Aha! Great answer. Had me scratching my head, even though it seems so obvious now.

Comment: ahh, that makes so much more sense! Thank you!

Comment: what is the difference b/w & and && though

Comment: && is the comparison operator. & is the unary/binary operator. For example 60 & 13 = 12 since (0011 1100 & 0000 1101 = 0000 1100).